# For what reasons is a class expunged instead of dropped?

Tags: transcript-of-records

Instead of having a class dropped, withdrawn or set as incomplete it is possible to have it expunged from your transcript record. Why does this happen typically?

Comment: It will depend largely on the institution. (I would guess)

Some things most will do.
For example if it was a data entry mistake by admin.
Some less will do:
For example a data entry mistake by you (Eg if you accidentally enrolled and didn't notice til you got your exam timetable).
Some none will do: Eg you withdrew because you have failed enough prior tests that even 100% the exam  will not let you pass.

I've heard friend of friends of mine got expunged (or possibly withdrawn changed to "With Drawn without penality") for medical reasons

Comment: @Oxinabox you thought enough to comment would you upvote so that i could please ask another question

Comment: What's the distinction between "dropped" and "expunged?" At my school, an undergrad who drops a course in the first half of the term doesn't have it appear on the transcript at all; would that be considered "expunged?"

Comment: @cpast Expunged is what they can do after the drop period, under special circumstances. It means that the class still won't show up on your transcript, even though you dropped it too late.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the institution. I had a class dropped as an undergraduate (my advisor told me that if I registered as extracurricular, I wouldn't have to take the final exam, I would just get a pass/fail based on my homeworks. I found out he was wrong about that 2 weeks before the final when they sent out the exam schedule and I was registered for the final exam in that class (turns out the changed the rules for extracurricular classes the year before). Fortunately, I had the conversation with my advisor over email, so it was declared clerical error and the class was expunged from my record. Another student in my class was hit by a car a few days after the last day to drop classes and hurt badly enough that he needed a semester off. All of the classes he was registered for were expunged from his record, and his transcript reads that semester as free for health reasons.

Most universities will expunge a class from your records if you have a good reason: typically clerical error or health (including mental health) reasons. Some universities will instead let you "withdraw without penalty" if it is for health reasons. The only way to know how your university does it is to check the regulations or ask your advisor.